# Vertical line is not shown on my HoloViews scatter plot because it's outside the x-range of my scatterplot

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

I have a scatter plot and want to add a vertical line to it as a marker.

However the scatter plot has x-range 0 to 2, but my vertical line is at x-range 6, so it's falling outside of the x-range of my scatter plot and not shown automatically.

What can I do to make my vertical line shown regardless of the x-ranges of my plot?

**Sample code:**

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

# my vline is not shown automatically because it's
# outside the range of my hv.Curve()
hv.Curve([[0,3], [1,4], [2,5]]) * hv.VLine(6)
```

**Example plot (which doesnt show Vline):**

[image: line plot without extra vertical line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You can of course **change the xlim manually** with:
`hv.VLine(4).opts(xlim=(0, 7))`

**2)** use **.opts(apply_ranges=True)** without having to look what the range on the x-axis should be:

```
curve = hv.Curve([[0,3], [1,4], [2,5]])

# use apply_ranges=True
vline = hv.VLine(4).opts(apply_ranges=True, line_width=10)

curve * vline
```

The same thing works also for hv.VSpan() and hv.HLine().

**3) Use spikes [hv.Spikes](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Spikes.html) instead of vertical lines:**
The advantage of Spikes is that it will also adjust the x-range for you automatically.

```
curve = hv.Curve([[0,3], [1,4], [2,5]])

# use apply_ranges=True
spikes = hv.Spikes([4]).opts(
    spike_length=3.0, 
    line_width=5,
    line_dash='dashed',
)

curve * spikes
```

**Resulting plot:**

[image: use .opts(apply_ranges=True) to change your xrange automatically]